# itext7 - how to get document signed content?

Tags: java, itext7

I'm looking for something like `getSignedContent` on [PDFBox](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/digitalsignature/PDSignature.java) to get the Signed content of the file (not the signature).

> Return the signed content of the document. This is not a PDF file, nor
> is it the PDF file before signing, it is the byte sequence made of the
> input minus the area where the signature bytes will be

How to do it with itext?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best way, but seems to work:

```
        PdfArray byteRange = signature.getByteRange();
        File signed = File.createTempFile("signed_", ".bin");

        RandomAccessFileOrArray rf = reader.getSafeFile();
        try (InputStream rg = new RASInputStream(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createRanged(rf.createSourceView(), byteRange.toLongArray()));
             OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream(signed)) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int rd;
            while ((rd = rg.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                result.write(buf, 0, rd);
            }
        }
```